# How to compare two last updated entities from two different table Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, database-design, trigger, query

I have 2 tables named as price and price_history. price_history table is automatically filled by triggers from price table just before updating the price table. I would like see the change at the new table named as change and fill it by triggers again just before the price table will be updated.

### Function:

```
create or Replace function test()
returns trigger
as
$$
begin

update change set change_= SELECT price_ FROM price ORDER BY(last_update) DESC LIMIT 1 - SELECT price_ FROM price_history ORDER BY(last_update) DESC LIMIT 1 ;
return new;

end;
$$
language plpgsql;
```

Trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER testtrig
BEFORE UPDATE
ON price
FOR EACH ROW 
EXECUTE PROCEDURE test();
```

> I get error while using the querry --> SELECT price_ FROM price ORDER BY(last_update) DESC LIMIT 1 - SELECT price_ FROM price_history ORDER BY(last_update) DESC LIMIT 1 ;

Can you help me please?
Thanks

Comment: Error? What error? I don't see no error. Also, what you call a query is not; it doesn't follow any defined syntax rules.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing some parenthesis around your select queries.

But i don't understand completely what you try to achieve, i think you should at least also transfer the produdct_id, because for now you get a price from a unknown product.

```
create or Replace function test() returns trigger as $$ begin

update change 
set change_= (SELECT price_ FROM price ORDER BY(last_update) DESC LIMIT 1) - (SELECT price_ FROM price_history ORDER BY(last_update) DESC LIMIT 1) ; 
return new;

end; $$ language plpgsql;




CREATE TRIGGER testtrig BEFORE UPDATE ON price 
FOR EACH ROW 
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE test();
```

Comment: Frankly, I would like to achieve price change of the item. Price table is always up to date. Old prices is sent to the price_history table. I was thinking that holding the change data on different table makes it faster in terms of database performance. Doesn't it?

Comment: Your function query gets the last price entered in the database , which isn't propably the correct value . It is hard to tell what you are trying to do but you have the production your trigger so use that to get the last prices